Is there an optimal way to simulate the material with nearest, next-nearest and 2nd-next-nearest Heisenberg exchange interaction?
As the question title described, for a material with the following parameters: nearest Heisenberg exchange interaction ($J_1$), next-nearest Heisenberg exchange interaction ($J_2$), next-next-nearest Heisenberg exchange interaction ($J_3$), DMI, and magnetic anisotropy, just like the following Hamiltonian described
$$ H = J_1 \sum_{\langle ij \rangle}\vec m_i\cdot\vec m_j+ J_2\sum_{\langle\langle ij \rangle\rangle}\vec m_i\cdot\vec m_j+ J_3\sum_{\langle\langle\langle ij \rangle\rangle\rangle}\vec m_i\cdot\vec m_j+ \sum_{\langle ij \rangle}\vec D_{ij}\vec m_i\times\vec m_j- K\sum_i(m_i^z)^2 $$
The spin configuration will transit from Skyrmion to In-plane FM as these parameters changed, for example. Is there an optional way to simulate this transition? I have read the documents of oommf and mumax3, but I did not found a solution.
Reference: arXiv 2403.05747.

Have you lookid into the Model Hamiltonian Package?
